# React svg from public folder

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to import the svg from the public folder.

How can I do that using import?

I've tried:

```
import Avatar_1 from './public/avatar_1.svg';
```

but I'm still getting "Module not found: Can't resolve './public/avatar_1.svg'"

Is there a way to use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's not possible to access the public folder from src, so I did the following:

```
import { ReactComponent as Avatar1 } from './assets/avatar_1.svg';
```

and it worked.

How to use it:

```
<Avatar1 />
```

Please note that the `ReactComponent as` part of the import is mandatory, and that your new component name, like `Avatar1`, should always start with a capital letter. Otherwise react won't recognize this as a react component.

Answer (score 0):

Create **'icons'** folder in Public Directory and Use this code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';    
const iconPath = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/icons/';

export default class TestComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
render(){
return (<img
    src={`${iconPath}icon-arrow.svg`}
    alt="more"
/>)
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to use import as a React Component and then use <Avatar_1 />